# Running a repeated mocha test for a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am new `mocha` and I need to run one test `100` times. In the following code, a function `regexTest` is tested for `true`.

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('regexTest',function() {
    it('should return true if the string starts with a number',function() {
        var i = 1;
        while(i++ <= 100) {
            assert.equal(true,regexTest(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)));
        }
    });
})

function regexTest(randStr) {
    let match = randStr.match(/^\d+/);
    if(match && match.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to run a repeated test, inside a while loop. Also, I doubt the results because no matter what, it always returns passed for a single test.

What could be a better approach here?

Comment: The problem with the code you have is that you are actually only testing the last random string generated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem with the code you have is that you are actually only testing the last random string generated.

Also, as mentioned by [@Geotob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4033315/geotob), it will nicer if you print the string on which the test case failed.

You could frame it like:

```
var assert = require('assert');

    function makeTest() {
        describe('regexTest', function () {
            var i = 0;
            while (i++ <= 20) {
                it('should return true if the string starts with a number', function () {
                    var i = 0;
                    let str = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
                    let output = regexTest(str);
                    assert.equal(true, output, `Failed on ${str}`);
                });
            }

        });
    }


    function regexTest(randStr) {
        let match = randStr.match(/^\d+/);
        if (match && match.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    makeTest();
```

This should work fine.

**Notes**:

- [Dynamically generating tests](http://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests) from the mocha doc.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, @Koko is testing every random string that is generated? The test will fail as soon as one of the random strings does not match?

Comment: @Geotob It won't. Have done a small change in my answer.

Comment: "you are actually only testing the last random string generated" is wrong. The loop is executed up to 100 times, and `assert` is called every time. You can verify by adding a simple `console.log` to the loop in @Koko's example.

Answer (score 0):

So first off , your code seems correct and running it locally returns:

```
~/P/test ➤ node_modules/.bin/mocha x.js 

  regexTest
    1) should return true if the string starts with a number


  0 passing (10ms)
  1 failing
```

As far as I remember there is no official way to repeat an assert statement, so running it inside a loop should be fine.

You might want to consider adding a more verbose failure message to your assert statement though, something like:

```
while(i++ <= 100) {
  let testStr = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  assert.equal(true, regexTest(testStr), 'Test failed on ' + testStr);
}
```

(and just in case it helps, you don't need that `if` block in your `regexTest` function. Simply end with `return match && match.length`)

Comment: But it doesn't seem to run the 100 tests. Why does it always return `one failure`? Also, if the function returns `true` always, it would say `passed 1 test`. Why is that?

Comment: Because a *test* here is everything inside a single `it(...)` function, so technically there's only one test. You can have as many `asserts` as you want in that single test. The test then fails as soon as the first `assert` fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you assert at every single execution of the loop, test will end at first assertion error. If you want to see how many times your test failed out of 100, you can store test results in an array, you can do something like:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('regexTest',function() {
    it('should return true if the string starts with a number',function() {
        var i = 1;
        var errorsArray = [];
        while(i++ <= 100) {
            var randomNumber = Math.random();
            if(!randomNumber.toString(36).substring(7)){
                errorsArray.push(randomNumber);
            }
        }
        assert.equal(0, errorsArray.length, errorsArray);
    });
})
```